# Differentiating a sum (sigma notation)

Tags: derivatives, summation

What is the approach for differentiating a sum (complete not partial differential) such as

$$S = -k_B \sum_i [(1-f_i)\ln(1-f_i) +f_i\ln(f_i)]$$

Can I ignore the sum and differentiate w.r.t. $f_i$ as normal? Or actually if I can ignore the sum then differentiate w.r.t. f. Could I also ignore the sum when drawing a graph and plot 
$$y = [(1-f)\ln(1-f) +f\ln(f)]$$

Thanks!

Comment: What are you differentiating with respect to?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Differentiating w.r.t. $f_i$.

Comment: Are you taking $\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial f_n}$ or $\dfrac{d\, S}{d\,f_n}$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Complete differential. It's a good point, I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have

$$  y=(1-f)\ln(1-f)+f\ln(f)$$

then you have a differential

$$ dy=[\ln(f)-\ln(1-f)]df $$

Therefore, given

\begin{equation}
S = -k_B \Sigma_i [(1-f_i)\ln(1-f_i) +f_i\ln(f_i)]\\
\end{equation}

you have

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dS}{df_n}=-k_B\sum_i\left[\ln(f_i)-\ln(1-f_i)\right]\dfrac{df_i}{df_n}
\end{equation}

If by "ignoring the sum" when differentiating, the answer is "yes" if you mean "just integrate the expression inside the sum."

But if $S$ is a function of several variables $\{f_i\}$ then its graph will be a higher dimensional object and the sum cannot be ignored.

Comment: I would expect that $\dfrac{df_i}{df_n} = 0$ if $n \ne i$.

Comment: Where does $f_n$ come from? Is it the same as $f_i$? I need to look at which $f_i$ maximises S.

Comment: $f_i = \frac{n_i}{g_i}$, I know very little about how those two behave except I'm pretty sure they're constant if $i$ is kept constant, and only change when $i$ is varied. So thinking about it, isn't the sum the only thing that means there is a graph that isn't a flat line?

Comment: @martycohen OP says he wants ordinary derivatives, not partial derivatives  so one cannot assume that $\dfrac{df_i}{df_n}=0$ for $n\ne i$. No mention is made of how many independent variables $f_i$ there are. In my answer, $f_n$ is merely one of the $f_i$, take your pick. I did not bother to break out the term $n=i$ from the summation. Now OP is saying that the $f_i$ are constants, not variables, so I am completely in the dark.

Comment: If, as you say, the $f_i$ are variables and not constants, then, for example for $i=1$, $f_1$ is a variable and $f_1=\frac{n_1}{g_1}$ at least one of which must also be a variable. If $f_1$ is a constant then one cannot take $\dfrac{dS}{df_1}$.